# Transforming the result of an AngularFIre result to a custom type and have it be iterable

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I have a service method that looks like this:

```
getManufacturers(): Observable<Manufacturer> {
    return this.db.list('/manufacturers')
      .flatMap(mfg => { return mfg; })
      .map(mfg => new Manufacturer(mfg));
}
```

What I really want it to return is `Observable<Manufacturer[]>` so that I can iterate over it in my template by using the | async pipe.

I'm new to Observables and Angular2+ so I'm sure that I'm just not understanding how to wire these things up.  I undertand that flatMap is unwrapping the array that angular fire is sending back (into individual elements) so that I can map/transform each element into a specific class type. But, then I lose that it is an array that is being returned. So that this no longer works:

```
<div *ngFor="let listing of listings | async">
</div>
```

Should I, instead of doing the flatMap, map the whole array from the incoming native type to an array of my custom classes?

Is there a better approach for adding the custom functionality for the data types being returned from the angular fire call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After thinking about this some more, I guess my wondering about mapping the array of generic objects to a new array of Manufacturers started making sense (instead of breaking it into its elements, transforming, and trying to reassemble).

Since the incoming value on the stream was an array simply mapping it to a new array with the object types I want made sense to me.

So, I adjusted my service method to look like this:

```
getManufacturers(): Observable<Manufacturer[]> {
  return this.db.list('/manufacturers')
  .map(mfgs => mfgs.map(mfg => new Manufacturer(mfg)));
}
```

I'm still curious if there was a better way (more reactive) to handle this. For example, a better way to handle the transformation of the array to the new type to break down the array as I had originally thought and reassemble into a new array.

The template then uses `<div *ngFor="let listing of listings"></div>` (where listings is the manufacturers array (note no more async).

Comment: Still learning rxjs myself, maybe flatMapIterable is what you're looking for